# Problem purchasing android apps

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, paid-apps

I bought humble bundle for PC, which comes with some games available on android market, played the games a bit, uninstalled, then I went to market and wanted to buy a second copy of OSMOS HD, but it still shows as purchased and I don't have it on my Galaxy S2 anymore, and yes, I cleared cache, uninstalled market updates, cleared dalvik cache, reinstalled and uninstalled game to see if it worked...I wanted to buy it again because of the easier updates, but market won't allow me.

Also, I installed another game, Generation of Chaos which I didn't pay for it, then uninstalled, did the same procedures as OSMOS HD above, and I want to buy it on market, but it still shows as purchased and will not download.

Any ideas/tips ?

Comment: You said you cleared the cache, but did you clear the **data** for the Market?  If that doesn't work and everything is uninstalled, I'd contact the HB people.

Comment: That's pretty odd that they show up as purchased. I also bought the bundle and the Market will prompt me to update Osmos, but then it will specifically tell me that I have **not** purchased it and it won't let me update.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the Play Store falsely linked some apps to your account that you installed from third-party sources.

This has been in some 3.5.x version, and now it works as expected.